# editing httpd.conf on apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, httpd.conf, uwamp

I'm trying to make my apache visible on my local network for being able to acces my wordpress site hosted there, by editing *httpd.conf* file on */bin/apache/conf/* and im getting a Permision Error, but I can't find any clear content on the Internet.

Im using UWAMP 3.1.0 and It must be something related with this part of the code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#UWAMP Generate Virtual Host
    DocumentRoot "F:/UwAmp/www/"
    ServerName "main-serveur"
    Alias "/mysql/" "F:/UwAmp/phpapps/phpmyadmin/"
    Alias "/mysql" "F:/UwAmp/phpapps/phpmyadmin/"
    Alias "/uwamp/" "F:/UwAmp/phpapps/uwamp/"
    Alias "/uwamp" "F:/UwAmp/phpapps/uwamp/"
    <Directory "F:/UwAmp/phpapps/phpmyadmin/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes 
        Require local
    </Directory>
    <Directory "F:/UwAmp/phpapps/uwamp/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes 
        Require local
    </Directory>
    <Directory "F:/UwAmp/www/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
        Require local   
    </Directory>
```

more concretely at the end:

```
<Directory "F:/UwAmp/www/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
        Require local   
</Directory>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xFEC.jpg) is what I get after entering the IP where the site is hosted.

sorry for asking something so simple but I'm learning

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, your question is very unclear. How are you accessing the server, What unexpected behavior are you seeing? Please share any error messages/logs. Is this a programming question or have you looked on serverfault which may be more relevant.

Comment: Thank you @SteveE. for answering. I edited the post adding the error that I get when trying to acces via browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{ONLINE_MODE}

```
If UwAmp is on Online mode, your website is available for all.
{ONLINE_MODE} will be replaced by :
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

If UwAmp is on Offline mode, your website is available only for your computer.
{ONLINE_MODE} will be replaced by :
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: Okay I just have realised of an option on UWamp, called Online /Offline mode, found it because of the text you told me, 'online/offline mode'. Btw, I coudn't find  that option in httpd.conf. Thanks!